# what is flipv and fliph : is it removed from css3

Tags: css

```
      <style>
        <!--
       .verticaltext {
           writing-mode: tb-rl;
           filter: flipv fliph;
        }
       -->
       </style>
```

what is flipv and fliph ? Even if i remove them I can see the text vertical ? I have seen many places it's used and at some not...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are [proprietary IE CSS things](http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/visual-filters.shtml) that you can do to flip text vertically or horizontally.